# Correct use of comma in "Hamburgers first, the rest second"

Tags: commas, comma-splices, slogan

A slogan for a hamburger bar I saw was "Hamburgers first, the rest second" meaning that they (hamburgers) are considered above all else. Is this a comma splice and should there be second comma "Hamburgers first, the rest, second"?

Comment: Related: [Eclipse first, the rest nowhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(horse)).

Answer (score 1):

It is not a comma splice because neither "Hamburgers first" nor "the rest second" is an independent clause with subject and verb. Particularly, "the rest second" makes no sense on its own.

Comment: The entire thing is also not a strictly grammatical sentence. (Unless you consider it an elliptical form of the imperative *Eat hamburgers first, the rest second.*) But, as a slogan, that doesn't matter.